# Python Tkinter - How to display JPG image in Button

Tags: python, tkinter, jpeg

using python 2.7 and Tkinter, how can i make an image, that when clicked on runs a function?
i was thinking about using something like

```
Button(...,foto = "mypic.jpg",command=myfunc)
```

but i don't manage.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I came across the same problem.  The official TKinter documentation (here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) says it should be possible, but I haven't found that it works in Python 2.7 (look for the compound option) :(

Answer (score 2):

After looking around a bit, here's what I got. I haven't tested this, though.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("mypic.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

Button(...,image=photo,command=myfunc)
```

The `foto` should be `image` here. `PIL` is a dependency you have to obtain. Hope this helps.

Comment: AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'open'

Answer (score -1):

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("mypic.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

Button(...,image=photo,command=myfunc)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please refrain from copying and pasting the exact same answer as was posted earlier.